# Executing shell command produces nothing

Tags: perl, docker, busybox, alpine-linux

I am running shell commands inside my Perl script, but it does not work as expected. I am in a container with Alpine Linux as my base image.

my Perl version v5.24.0.

```
perl -e 'my $TEST = `ls -al`; print $TEST'
```

This prints nothing, but works on another system where I have Perl v5.6.1 on Red Hat Linux.

Comment: @toolic it prints 0

Comment: @Michael ls -al prints the content of the directory, it's not empty

Comment: @toolic tilda was missing, output of `perl -e 'my $TEST = `ls -al`; print $TEST; print $? if $?' ` is -1

Comment: When `$?` is set to `-1`, the error is in `$!`. So change `print $? if $?` to `print $? == -1 ? $! : $?`

Comment: Whats your `docker run` or CMD? I think that you don't have PATH defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a possibility that **maybe** is your problem.

I think you don't have the PATH env var defined.

Try this using full path of `ls` (/bin/ls):

```
perl -e 'my $TEST = `/bin/ls -al`; print $TEST'
```

I've tested similar scenario:

Emptying PATH:

```
PATH="" /usr/bin/perl -e'
   my $output = `ls -al`;
   if (!defined($output)) {
      die("readpipe: $!\n")                             if $? == -1;
      die("Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
      die("Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n")  if $? >> 8;
   }

   print($output);
'
```

Output:

```
readpipe: No such file or directory
```

Using absolute path (/bin/ls):

```
PATH="" /usr/bin/perl -e'
       my $output = `/bin/ls -al`;
       if (!defined($output)) {
          die("readpipe: $!\n")                             if $? == -1;
          die("Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
          die("Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n")  if $? >> 8;
       }

   print($output);
'
```

Output:

```
total 4531444
drwxr-xr-x  7 rbravo rbravo       4096 May 30 19:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 63 root   root         4096 Apr  7 14:11 ..
-rw-------  1 rbravo rbravo      12248 May 30 19:39 .bash_history
...
```

Comment: it works with the absolute path. so this `perl -e 'my $TEST = `/bin/ls -al`; print $TEST'` works. But I have PATH env set correctly PATH has /bin

Comment: Can you try this? `perl -e 'my $TEST = \`/usr/bin/env\`; print $TEST'`

Comment: that prints all the environment variables and PATH still has /bin

Comment: Can you provide us the scenario to reproduce the issue? A complete Dockerfile would be great. But if this answer is enough, that's ok

Comment: I am using Alpine as my base image. I have node, ngnix and couple other scripts, I am copying to my container. what i have for perl is just `apk add --no-cache perl`. I have not explicitly set PATH or any environment variable

Comment: I've tried your command also based on alpine, but it works. I'm not sure what could be happening. What triggers your perl execution? Is it embedded inside another script?

Comment: Inside my perl script, i am executing some shell commands. It's not embedded in any other script.

Comment: I am print PATH inside the same perl script it has /bin and /usr/bin.

Comment: Please, another try: `perl -e 'my $TEST = \`PATH=/bin ls -l\`; print $TEST'`. To see whether makes any difference